# AES encryption and input string encoding

Tags: c#, encryption, character-encoding

Can someone explain me why these two pieces of code don't give the same result, and yet the StreamWriter in the 2nd example is using the UTF8 encoding:

```
var TokenEncryptKey = "D268197CF891452844441A143AAEAAEB";
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TokenEncryptKey);

        var alg = new RijndaelManaged();
        alg.Key = key;
        alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        var mem = new MemoryStream();

        CryptoStream encryptStream = new CryptoStream(mem, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        var validReservation = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
        encryptStream.Write(validReservation, 0, validReservation.Length);
        encryptStream.Flush();
        encryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        Console.Out.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(mem.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mem.Length));
```

2nd Example

```
var TokenEncryptKey = "D268197CF891452844441A143AAEAAEB";
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TokenEncryptKey);

        var alg = new RijndaelManaged();
        alg.Key = key;
        alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        var mem = new MemoryStream();

        CryptoStream encryptStream = new CryptoStream(mem, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(encryptStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.Write("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
        sw.Flush();
        encryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        Console.Out.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(mem.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mem.Length));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `StreamWriter(encryptStream, Encoding.UTF8)`, this will add a Unicode BOM (byte order mark) of 3 bytes. To avoid that, use `new StreamWriter(m, new UTF8Encoding())` instead.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` will not add the BOM even though the encoding is setup to do that - you can retrieve it if needed using `GetPreamble` instead.